# How to mine Monero on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, linux

I tried to mine on Ubuntu but it didn't work. please tell me the right way to mine on Ubuntu. Also I got a problem while registering on *https://supportxmr.com/*: its home page is not like same which I have seen on a Youtube video,
now it looks more like this:

[image]

I don't know what to do from here and how to register myself.

Comment: Please try to provide a lot more information.  No one can help you if we don't know what you've done.  If you are unable to provide more details, this question will probably be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XMRig, connect it to supportxmr

You can use https://xmrig.com/wizard to create your config file.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I too am attempting to start mining Monero (XMR) but I am using 19.10 with a AMD Radeon that has no officially supported driver by the vendor.

I at least managed to get CPU mining going and this was the link that helped me out the most: https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-mine-monero

Hope this helps!